# Unable to read HTTP Statuscode in SOAP call with WCF Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, soap

I'm trying to send a request to a SOAP service using the following code. When something goes wrong on the server we always get the same error. The only thing that's different is the HTTP Statuscode.

We're trying to send a request to a SOAP service using the following snippet. When an error occurs on the SOAP service we always receive the same error message. This means we're not able to handle specific errors which is needed for our business flows. The only thing that is different is the HTTP Statuscode but we are not able to read it. How can we find out what the HTTP statuscode is?

The third party behind the SOAP service is not willing to change this behavior. We are using .NET 6.0.

```
public Task<MyResponseModel> SendAsync(MyRequestModel request)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
    {
        OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    };
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://example.com/");
    ChannelFactory<IWcfClient> channelFactory = null;
    try
    {
        channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWcfClient>(binding, endpointAddress);
        channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new InspectMessageBehavior());
        IWcfClient channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return channel.SendItemAsync(request);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (channelFactory != null)
            channelFactory.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

- We tried reading the exception
- We used an implementation of IEndpointBehavior to try and read the statuscode
- We tried to capture all the events on ChannelFactory like Faulted and Closed. Faulted wasn't even triggered.

Comment: The status message should be in response.  If connection closes without a response than channel factory is null.  If you are not capturing the exception than a library captured the exception and did not include a THROW.  Without the THROW the exception can only be captured once.   Are you getting a timeout?  Try increasing the length of timeout.  Usually the default timeout 30 seconds.  How long does it take before the error occurs?  Is it always the same amount of time?

Comment: **WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode：** It can obtain the HTTP status code returned by the WCF server to the client. You can try this method.